# CSS non sibling event hack to trigger dynamic content display / uncheck

Tags: html, css

I have a website that displays content based on items checked in a menu list. If the screen width gets too small the menu is rotated and hidden. Additionally, a burger button is displayed. If the burger button gets activated (checkbox as well), the menu is unhidden and the content is hidden.

Neither the content nor the menu have access to the checkbox behind the burger button, because they are children of a sibling of the burger button.

As a result, if a menu item was checked, the burger button is not unchecked, and the visitor needs to click on the burger button again to close the menu and see the content.

Somehow I need to find a hack to uncheck the burger button, if a different menu item was selected, or if a menu item was clicked.

JavaScript is not required yet and shall never be used.

I hope someone knows a hack to fix this - I am clueless in this case...

[image: Problem overview]

Comment: You might need to add a minimal amount of html and css to illustrate your problem.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thank you for your numerous comments.

The answer is quite simple: CSS3 can't do what I tried to achieve. There was no trick at all to get this done, not even involving the `:target` pseudo-class, because CSS can't manipulate and reset the URL anchor, neither can it untick the checkbox. That caused the menu staying visible after selecting the content as mentioned above.
As a result, I have rewritten the whole website (well, not the content to be precise).

There is a theoretically simple solution: Using sibling radio buttons for all controls.
This means:

1. I have one radio button for the burger menu. It accesses the following (sibling) `<div>` element with the adjacent sibling combinator (+) and toggles the burger menu on and off. (Which results in a changed `visibility` property.)
2. I have multiple radio buttons for the content. Succeeded by their respective content `div` analogously to (1.).
3. I have multiple labels all over the place that address these radio buttons by using their `for` attribute. Fortunately, the `for` attribute has multiplicity `1:n`, so that it was possible to address the content `<div>`s by both, the `<nav>`-bar, displayed for high resolution devices, as well as the burger menu, displayed on low resolution devices on click on the burger button which is not visible for high resolution displays.

So as a result, I don't do any menu transformations, but have just duplicated the `<label>`s for these toggles and display either the `<nav>` bar or the burger button.

Downsides:

1. I lost the ability to keep the style of the `<label>`s for the currently active content changed while this content is displayed, since these `<label>` elements are not siblings of their corresponding checkbox/radio anymore, but on `:hover` there is an effect.
2. It is not possible to have the burger menu displayed leaving the current content displayed as well in the background. Both are and need to be in the same radio button group, which means that the burger menu is displayed instead of other content until a label is clicked in the burger menu.

Why am I even doing this (Benefits):

1. From my perspective, running scripts on a visitors machine is like highjacking their compute power on their device in their sphere and by forcing them to activate JavaScript or other stuff, exposing them to serious risks that could be avoided. So as a result, I consider the unnecessary use of JavaScript as an unethical act.
2. With this hiding technique of the content I am able to transfer all the content to the visitor a single time and allow for a perfect experience once the content is loaded.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Let me quickly explain how I use to surf the internet:

a) I have NoScript activated by default.

b) If I want to get some news and the site requests me to activate JavaScript, I rather die dumb.

c) If I like to research something I will find another source that displays sufficiently well without JavaScript

d) If I need to enable JavaScript to survive, e.g. for my bank account or my job, I will enable it.

As a result: I simply can't use this myself. That would be completely against my values. I hope very much that CSS4 can bring required improvemennts.

Comment: I used to be on that bandwagon too, and everything I built would work without JS - but it finally reached a point that it wasn't worth it. Analytics was telling us that the JS-disabled population had dwindled to literal zero. Good on you for holding strong.